# Why Angularjs shows always error message?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

In my project I use angularjs form validation, for this I have written controller:

```
// Make an appointment
angular.module('app', []).controller('AppointmentController', ['$scope','$http', function($scope, $http) {

            $scope.response = { response : '' };
            $scope.formData = {
                id: '',
                reason: '',
                phone: 0,
                day : 0,
                month : 0,
                year : 0,
                type : false
            };

            console.log($scope.formData.phone); // Show nothing

            $scope.AppointmentSubmit = function () {

                if ($scope.userForm.$valid) {
                    var request = $http({
                        method: "POST",
                        url: "/other/Appointments",
                        data: $.param($scope.formData),
                        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
                    });

                    /* Check whether the HTTP Request is successful or not. */
                    request.success(function (data) {

                    });
                }
            }

        }]);
```

My HTML form looks like as:

```
<div ng-app="app">
<div class="modal fade appointments-modal in" ng-controller="AppointmentController" id="appointmentsModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="false" style="display: block;"><div class="modal-backdrop fade in" style="height: 787px;"></div>
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span><span class="sr-only">x</span></button>
                <h3 class="text-center">Titlte</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body log-form">
                <form ng-hide="response.type" class="form-horizontal" id="loginForm" name="appointment" novalidate="">
                    <div class="form-group birhday-group">

<div class="selectDate">
    <select name="day[]" ng-model="formData.day" required="">
<option value="0">D</option>
</select>   <select name="mouth[]" ng-model="formData.mouth" required="">
<option value="0">M</option>

</select>
            <select name="year[]" ng-model="formData.year" required="">
<option value="0">Y</option>
<option value="2016">2016</option>
<option value="2015" selected="selected">2015</option>
</select>   </div>                        <div class="form-error" ng-show="appointment.day.$invalid &amp;&amp; !appointment.day.$pristine">
                            You must to enter day for appointment
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-error" ng-show="appointment.month.$invalid &amp;&amp; !appointment.month.$pristine">
                            You must to enter month for appointment
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-error" ng-show="appointment.year.$invalid &amp;&amp; !appointment.year.$pristine">
                            You must to enter year for appointment
                        </div>
                        <!--<div class="dropdown">
                            <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
                                2015
                                <span class="caret"></span>
                            </button>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                                <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
                                <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>-->
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input ng-model="formData.phone" type="text" value="" ng-minlength="7" ng-maxlength="13" class="form-control" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" pattern="(\+?\d[- .]*){7,13}" required="">
                        <div class="form-error" ng-show="appointment.phone.$invalid &amp;&amp; !appointment.phone.$pristine">
                            You must to enter own contact phone
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="form-group radio-group">
                        <textarea name="reason" ng-model="formData.reason" maxlength="150" placeholder="Reason" required=""></textarea>
                        <div class="form-error" ng-show="appointment.reason.$invalid &amp;&amp; !appointment.reason.$pristine">
                            You must to enter a reason of appointment
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-error" ng-show="response.type === 'error'">
                        <span>{{response.message}}</span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group submit-group">
                        <input type="hidden" name="id" ng-model="formData.id" value="" required="">
                        <button type="submit" ng-click="AppointmentSubmit()" ng-disabled="appointment.$invalid" id="SendRecord" class="btn">Make app</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In this HTML I determined angular's `ng-app="app"`, `ng-controller="AppointmentController"` and some `ng-model` at form.

When I open this window I always see displayed errors in blocks `class="form-error"`:

```
<div class="form-error" ng-show="appointment.reason.$invalid &amp;&amp; !appointment.reason.$pristine">
You must to enter a reason of appointment
</div>
```

Also If do `console.log()` a contoller returned nothing.
Why does it happen?

Comment: It is good, but why in controller is not changed variable `ng-model="phone"`  from form, when I am typing text in input?

Comment: please create another question for this since it is not part of the topic

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
ng-show="appointment.reason.$invalid && !appointment.reason.$pristine"
```

or even better

```
ng-show="appointment.reason.$invalid && appointment.reason.$dirty"
```

Answer (score 0):

console.log()` sends the value to the console, which can be seen in plunker or your web browser development tools by pressing f12.  It is working properly in my plunk.  I don't get the error message on your reason for appointment.

I also commented out your hidden id field in your html.  It was keeping your form from validating, so you'll need to find another way to handle this.

You can view my plunk here: http://plnkr.co/edit/5viBuC5V9ZB2U8P5pDeI
Good luck!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<script data-require="jquery@2.1.3" data-semver="2.1.3" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<link data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="3.3.2" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="3.3.2" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script data-require="angular.js@1.4.0-beta.5" data-semver="1.4.0-beta.5" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-beta.5/angular.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div ng-app="app">
<div class="modal fade appointments-modal in" ng-controller="AppointmentController" id="appointmentsModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="false" style="display: block;">
  <div class="modal-backdrop fade in" style="height: 787px;"></div>
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
          <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
          <span class="sr-only">x</span>
        </button>
        <h3 class="text-center">Title</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body log-form">
        <form ng-hide="response.type" class="form-horizontal" id="loginForm" name="appointment" novalidate ng-submit="AppointmentSubmit()">
          <div class="form-group birhday-group">
            <div class="selectDate">

              <select name="day" type="number" ng-model="formData.day" required>
                 <option value="0">D</option>
                <option value="0">13</option>
              </select>
              <select name="month" type="number" ng-model="formData.month" required>
                <option value="0">M</option>
                <option value="0">10</option>
              </select>
              <select name="year" type="number" ng-model="formData.year" required>
                <option value="0">Y</option>
                <option value="2016">2016</option>
                <option value="2015" selected="selected">2015</option>
              </select>
            </div>

            <div class="error" ng-show="appointment.day.$invalid && !appointment.day.$pristine">
              You must enter the day for appointment
            </div>
            <div class="error" ng-show="appointment.month.$invalid && !appointment.month.$pristine">
              You must enter the month for appointment
            </div>
            <div class="error" ng-show="appointment.year.$invalid && !appointment.year.$pristine">
              You must enter the year for appointment
            </div>
            <!--<div class="dropdown">
                        <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
                            2015
                            <span class="caret"></span>
                        </button>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
                            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>-->
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input ng-model="formData.phone" ng-minlength="7" ng-maxlength="13" class="form-control" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" type='tel' pattern="(\+?\d[- .]*){7,13}" title='Phone Number (Format: +99(99)9999-9999)' required />
              <div>
                You've entered {{formData.phone}}
              </div>

            <div class="form-error" ng-show="appointment.phone.$invalid && !appointment.phone.$pristine">
              You must enter your contact phone
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group radio-group">
            <textarea name="reason" ng-model="formData.reason" maxlength="150" placeholder="Reason" required></textarea>
            <div class="form-error" ng-show="appointment.reason.$invalid && !appointment.reason.$pristine">
              You must enter a reason for this appointment
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-error" ng-show="response.type === 'error'">
            <span>{{response.message}}</span>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group submit-group">
           <!-- <input type="hidden" name="id" ng-model="formData.id" value="" required /> --> <!-- This kept your form from validating-->
            <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Make Apt" ng-disabled="appointment.$invalid" id="SendRecord"/>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>

</html>
```

And your script.js

```
// Code goes here

// Make an appointment
angular.module('app', []).controller('AppointmentController', ['$scope','$http', function($scope, $http) {

        $scope.response = { response : '' };
        $scope.formData = {
            id: '',
            reason: '',
            phone: 0,
            day : 0,
            month : 0,
            year : 0,
            type : false
        };

        console.log($scope.formData.phone); // Displays in the console, which you can see by pressing F12

        $scope.AppointmentSubmit = function() {

            if ($scope.appointment.$valid) {
                var request = $http({
                    method: "POST",
                    url: "/other/Appointments",
                    data: $.param($scope.formData),
                    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
                });

                /* Check whether the HTTP Request is successful or not. */
                request.success(function (data) {

                });
            }
        }

    }]);
```